# Spring pre-authenticated principal has changed to and will be reauthenticated

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using spring security with filters to authenticate the users. When several users access the same service in a multi-threaded environment, the principal has changed and going for re-authentication. The password is incorrect for the user and failed to authenticate.
How can I use the pre-authentication in a multi-thread environment?

Authentication using the filter.

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy" >
        <sec:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant" >
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="requestContextFilter,securityContextFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter,userRoleProcessingFilter" />
        </sec:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <bean id="requestContextFilter" class="org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter"/>


     <bean id="securityContextFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
         <constructor-arg>
             <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository"></bean>
         </constructor-arg>
         <property name="forceEagerSessionCreation" value="false"/>
     </bean>
 <bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter" >                    
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>


        <bean id="userRoleProcessingFilter"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
                <property name="principalRequestHeader" value="CUSTOM_USER" />
                <property name="credentialsRequestHeader" value="CUSTOM_CRED" />
                <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
                <property name="continueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication" value="false" />
                <property name="exceptionIfHeaderMissing" value="false"></property>
                <property name="checkForPrincipalChanges" value="true"></property>
        </bean>
         <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager" >
        <constructor-arg>
        <list>
                <ref bean="authenticationProvider"/>
        </list>
        </constructor-arg>
        </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationProvider" class="com.common.authorization.spring.custom.CustomAuthenticationProvider" >
        <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
            <bean class="com.common.authorization.spring.custom.CustomUserDetailsService">
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased" >
        <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="false"/>
        <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
                <property name="rolePrefix" value="" />
            </bean>
          </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Comment: "I am using spring security with filters to authenticate the users" - more information required

Comment: @DanielZ. Thank you for the reply. I added the filters section used in the applicationContext.xml file.